# Addition between 'int' and custom class

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was experimenting around with dunders in python when I found something:
Say I created a class:

```
class MyInt:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val

    def __add__(self, other):
        return self.val + other

a = MyInt(3)
```

The `__add__` works perfectly fine when this is run:

```
>>> print(a + 4)
7
```

However, when I ran this:

```
>>> print(4 + a)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'MyInt'
```

I know that the `int` class does not support adding with `MyInt`, but are there any workarounds for this?

Comment: It's called `__radd__`. Please see the [documentation for math-related dunders](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types).

Comment: Thanks, seems to work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is what the `__radd__` method is for - if your custom object is on the *right* side of the operator, and the left side of the operator can't handle it. Note that the left side of the operator will take precedence, if possible.

```
>>> class MyInt:
...     def __init__(self, val):
...         self.val = val
...     def __add__(self, other):
...         return self.val + other
...     def __radd__(self, other):
...         return self + other
... 
>>> a = MyInt(3)
>>> print(a + 4)
7
>>> print(4 + a)
7
```

The third 'hidden' method you can override, for any given operator, will be `__iadd__`, which corresponds to the assignment operator `+=`.

Comment: Shouldn't `__radd__` be `return self.value + other`?  :-)

Comment: I chose to use `self + other` instead of `self.value + other`, because `self + other` will redirect to `self.__add__()`. This way, if you want to change the behavior, you only need to change that method, and not `__radd__()` as well. That is, assuming `add` remains commutative.

Comment: Could also achieve that with `__radd__ = __add__`, I think (no idea what's better...).